# Amazon Redshift :- Enforce filter on query

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Is there a way to enforce filter on every query

Example:- select * from table 
should throw an error since there is **no filter on date**(example) column

Expected query to be select * from table where **date** = '2020-05-25'

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. This kind of constraint should be implemented in the application layer instead.

Comment: SQL is a flexible language where you decide what filter to apply to a query. Besides, you are not commonly running queries manually on the database; it's the app that requests the queries, so it's not easy to forget the filter(s).

Comment: _WHY_ do you want this functionality?